# Is there a word to describe an offensive term reclaimed by the offended group

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the process, or result of the process of, an offended group reclaiming a word for themselves. For example, it is common for gay people to call themselves queers, or sexually liberated women to call themselves sluts, or black people to refer to themselves by various offensive terms.

I seem to remember there is a term for this process. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reclaimed_word) suggests "reappropriation" but I seem to remember there is a more specific term.

Comment: Double standard?

Comment: _Reclaim_ as in {_Take Back the Night_ / _Reclaim the Night_}?

Comment: @Nile this isn't a political forum, it is a forum about words and grammar.

Comment: _Double standard_ is a legitimate lexical answer, except that it's two words instead of one. That it's also judgmental is a bonus. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke sorry I don't agree. "Double standard" is a judgement of the legitimacy of the process, it is not a name for the process of reclamation at all. It is consequentially political not linguistical.

Comment: Yes, it is a judgment about legitimacy, but I see nothing wrong with that. Human beings constantly judge themselves & others. What's the difference between gay people calling themselves "queer" & women calling themselves "sluts" (a recent reclamation in response to the Sandra Fluke/Rush Limbaugh to-do in the USA)? The point of using these words is either to hurt other people or to defuse the pain of the epithet by making it a commonplace expression, unless it's stipulated "a name I can call myself because I am one, but you can't because you aren't". That deserves judgment, IMHO.

Comment: @BillFranke there is certainly nothing wrong with judgement in the appropriate forum. And FWIW, in language, context is crucial to the meaning of words. It is certainly true that some words are acceptable in some contexts and not in others, and who is speaking the words most certainly in included in that context.

Comment: I agree that double standard is not the answer but I disagree that it is a political phrase. It is commonly used to describe a situation where different standards are applied to different people, groups, members, etc. By applying different rules or standards to my children I am applying a double standard. That is hardly political, since they are only seven.

Answer (score 5):

Reappropriation is defintely the best word I've come across for this but there's no term
which is commonly used so writing when that 'feminism is a reappropriation', you would probably need to elaborate by stating 'from the pejorative term assigned to women's right acitvists in the 18th century'.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation - Supports the use of the term in a specific manner.